# Is there a way to make Notifications appear on the lock screen after being seen as a banner? iOS12

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, unusernotificationcenter

In our app we are doing journey logging. The process where a user can press start, drive to their destination, press stop and their journey is recorded. With a notification reminding them that they are currently logging a journey.

I have the notifications working on android as follows: When the user taps start there is immediately a local notification icon at the top of the screen. When the phone is locked this notification also appears on the lock screen.

I have it kind of working on iOS where the notification will appear as a banner immediately after the user taps start. The notification will also appear in the notification center but not the lock screen.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/user-notifications/advanced-user-notifications?tabs=windows

Reading through the Microsoft documentation it seems that the notification is displayed depending on the state of the phone/app? Is there a way to instantly show the notification as a banner when the user taps start and also show the notification when the user locks their phone? All of this is assuming the user has the relevant settings turned on in iOS 12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Unfortunately** ,as far as I know , this can not be realized by third party Map.The notification in lock screen is a static notification display.

Alternatively, you can display alert to tell user updated info when in lock screen.

Otherwise , if using Apple's Map to navigation, when lock screen , you also can see full map view .

Here is the Apple [document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications) about UserNotifications .

Comment: I'm using google maps for both Android and iOS. Ah i thought it would have to come down to checking when then phone is locked and if journey logging is happening then update the notification to force one to show on the lock screen. I did a quick google yesterday on how to check for iOS device being locked and couldn't find anything straight away, any ideas how i'd achieve this? i'll keep looking in the meantime. Thanks.

Comment: @Jhardy Okey，maybe this can be helpful .https://www.addictivetips.com/ios/driving-directions-on-your-lock-screen-google-maps/ And IOS Widgets (https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/extensions/widgets/).

Comment: Sorry i'm using xamarin.forms.googlemaps so as far as i'm aware it doesn't/won't appear as a widget? i've just tried to edit my list of widgets and my app wasn't on the list. Looking at widgets, i'm not sure that is the best approach for me, is there anyway to detect if the iOS device has it's screen locked? I may be missing something as this is all a new part of iOS development for me. Thanks again.